# Multiple string replacement, using gsubfn() in R

Tags: r, string, gsub

I want to replace:

(1) `", "` (comma+space) with `"_"` (underscore)

(2) `"'"` (apostrophe) with `"'s"` (apostrophe+s)

```
library(gsubfn)
x <- c("Mary' car is red.", "A, B, C")
gsubfn(".", list(", " = "_", "'" = "'s"), x)
```

what I want is `"Mary's car is red."` and `"A_B_C"`, but the result is `"Mary's car is red."` and `"A, B, C"`. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
toreplace<-list(", " = "_", "'" = "'s")
gsubfn(paste(names(toreplace),collapse="|"),toreplace,x)
#[1] "Mary's car is red." "A_B_C"
```

The problem with your approach is that your pattern was just a single character (`.`) and couldn't match `", "`.

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- c("Mary' car is red.", "A, B, C")

l <- list(r1 = c("'","'s"),
          r2 = c(', ','_'))

gsub2 <- function(l, x, ...)
  do.call('gsub', c(list(x = x, pattern = l[1], replacement = l[2]), ...))
Reduce('gsub2', l, x, right = TRUE)
# [1] "Mary's car is red." "A_B_C"
```

Or more

```
l <- list(r1 = c("'","'s"),
          r2 = c(', ','_'),
          r3 = c('M', 'Mmmm'),
          r4 = c('\\br', 'rrrr'),
          r5 = c('\\.', '!!!'))

Reduce('gsub2', l, x, right = TRUE)
# [1] "Mmmmary's car is rrrred!!!" "A_B_C"
```